# NTP not getting through even to DMZ

Tags: router, firewall, udp, ntp, dmz

My home router seems to be blocking UDP 123.

```
sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```

works as expected, but

```
sudo ntpdate time.apple.com
```

I get: "no server suitable for synchronization found"

I can get a root shell on my router (yay!) and it seems to be running ntp, so maybe that's it?  But killing ntp on the router does not help, any iptables stuff I can think/find to set does not help, and setting DMZ to my laptop I can ssh from outside, but when I

```
sudo nc -u -l 123
```

I can't get a packet in from outside to that.

Direct DNS queries work, and as mentioned higher-port-number NTP works, so UDP in general is fine.

Why might this be happening?  Any way I can debug or fix it, short of swapping the firmware or getting a new router?